# Java method FileUtils.touch does not work correctly in final executable JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable, locked

I have maven project created in netbeans and there is Java class which contains static method isFileUnlocked. This method uses method org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.touch(String filePath) to check if the file is locked or not. This method works correctly when I run it from IDE Netbeans but from some reason it does not work after running of builded final JAR. I need to create correct version of executable JAR with expected behaviour as is in IDE.

I have also tried to test this problem scenarious and after I tried to test this method with an opening file there was no problem ie. method logs "file is unlocked" which is very strange.

Any idea why does the application have such behaviour?

Here is the method:

```
public static boolean isFileUnlocked(String filePath) {
    logger.debug("isFileUnlocked begin " + filePath);

    File file = new File(getValidExcelName(filePath));
    boolean isFileUnlocked = false;
    try {
        FileUtils.touch(file);
        isFileUnlocked = true;
       ogger.debug("file is unlocked");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("file is locked!");
        isFileUnlocked = false;
    }

    return isFileUnlocked;
  }
```

Comment: Are you talking about [FileUtils from apache commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#touch(java.io.File)) ?

Comment: Yes, correct. I will update this thread about full name of used package. Thanks